# Should we use Redis cache for labels

Tags: localization, redis, sails.js

I am developing a web application usinf Sails JS framework. Now I have one EJS file with around 1000 labels. The same labels also used in other EJS files.

To fetch these 1000 labels, I am thinking of storing them in Redis server in key/value pair. I am not much aware about Redis cache mechanism but I heard about it that it is very optimized way of fetching key/value pair data.

Any thoughts if Redis is optimum way for my requirement. Or I should use Sails locale.js file to fetch labels?

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's bad idea to use Redis for data you care about losing. There are some extremely high performance scenarios where it can be worth it, but it doesn't sound like you're dealing with something like that. The creators of Redis actually have a really [write up on this](http://redis.io/topics/persistence).

This particular part being key:

> RDB is NOT good if you need to minimize the chance of data loss in case Redis stops working (for example after a power outage). You can configure different save points where an RDB is produced (for instance after at least five minutes and 100 writes against the data set, but you can have multiple save points). However you'll usually create an RDB snapshot every five minutes or more, so in case of Redis stopping working without a correct shutdown for any reason you should be prepared to lose the latest minutes of data.

That said, you won't be updating this data regularly so it'd likely be fine, it's just extra headache for no real gain.

Comment: Your answer is completely misguiding. With AOF enable you will lose exactly as much data as you will lose with any other database.